# Google drive api with python

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to make an app where it displays the files and folders inside my google drive folder so I went to [google apis](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python#troubleshooting) and used the code I found on their page its here below

as I didn't expect it just let me log into my drive and then it returned me an error I'm providing a photo for it
[This is the error returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QNCp.png)
it says that

> Message='client_secret'
> Source=D:\Study\Computer Science\G10\Paython 2nd semester\python consol app\python consol app\python_consol_app.py
> StackTrace:
> File "D:\Study\Computer Science\G10\Paython 2nd semester\python consol app\python consol app\python_consol_app.py", line 48, in 
> main()

I managed to skip this error and renaming the json file and I solved this error only to find another error that says

***Message=Authorized user info was not in the expected format, missing fields client_secret, client_id, refresh_token.
Source=D:\Study\Computer Science\G10\Paython 2nd semester\python consol app\python consol app\python_consol_app.py
StackTrace:
File "D:\Study\Computer Science\G10\Paython 2nd semester\python consol app\python consol app\python_consol_app.py", line 48, in 
main()***

so I'm wondering how should I solve such an issue
also if my application can run into every single folder and subfolder

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
   
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
      
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and congrats on your first question!  For debugging exceptions in Python code it helps to paste the *full traceback*, otherwise from your screenshot it's difficult to say where your exception is coming from.  Your IDE should offer an option to copy the traceback.  Please edit your question and include the traceback as *text*, not as an image.

Comment: The full traceback could maybe be got from the "copy details" button in your screenshot

Comment: Make sure that you created [installed application credentials](https://youtu.be/qwqJcyLQSSQ) on google developer console and have enabled the google drive api.   It sounds like there's something wrong with the credentials.json file

Comment: Thank you for you comments I have edited my question to put the error full traceback and also I'm sure that I created the application credentials

Answer (score 4):

### Answer

First things first. It looks like you have some problem with your credentials. I would download the [credentials](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python#step_1_turn_on_the) file from the Quickstart again. Then, delete the generated `token` file in your working directory.

If you want to go deeper, you can [create](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects) a GCP project, and [enable](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/enable-api) the Google API as well as [generate](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en) the credentials, but this approach is not necessary if you don't want it.

Once you have Quickstart running, you can focus on your task. To display the files within your Drive, there is the [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) method, which returns all the files and folders in the current user's My Drive. To perform specific searches, you can use different parameters, but the most important is the `query`. You can read this [guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files) for some usage examples and further explanation.

### References:

- [Drive API: Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python#step_1_turn_on_the)
- [GCP: Creating and managing projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects)
- [GCP: Enabling an API](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/enable-api)
- [GCP: Setting up OAuth 2.0](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en)
- [Drive API: Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Drive: Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you renamed the downloaded credentials file as `credentials.json` and also you enable the according google api (drive,..)

Answer (score 1):

**first:**
Enable the API
Before using Google APIs, you need to turn them on in a Google Cloud project. You can turn on one or more APIs in a single Google Cloud project.
In the Google Cloud console, enable the Gmail API.
[from here](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=gmail.googleapis.com)

**secound:**
Authorize credentials for a desktop application
To authenticate as an end user and access user data in your app, you need to create one or more OAuth 2.0 Client IDs. A client ID is used to identify a single app to Google's OAuth servers. If your app runs on multiple platforms, you must create a separate client ID for each platform.
In the Google Cloud console, go to Menu menu > APIs & Services > Credentials.
Go to Credentials

Click Create Credentials > OAuth client ID.
Click Application type > Desktop app.
In the Name field, type a name for the credential. This name is only shown in the Google Cloud console.
Click Create. The OAuth client created screen appears, showing your new Client ID and Client secret.
Click OK. The newly created credential appears under OAuth 2.0 Client IDs.

**last**
download JSON file and rename file to credentials.json, and move the file to your working directory.

my problem solved

Comment: If not read the instructions clearly, then such issue can occurr. This answer was best for me. upvoting :)