# Authenticating to download an excel file from google drive (python)

Tags: python, google-sheets, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, pydrive

I want to download an excel file that's hosted on google docs. I have the file link (and thus the file id) and want to automate the process.
One thing to note is that I don't own the file, but my google account has permission to read it. I've seen some snippets of code from the google sheets api or pydrive but I still don't get the part about authentication, and have not been able to run the [code](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) successfully. I have 2 problems: (1) when setting the OAuth in the console I'm not sure what my URIs are supposed to be.
And (2) from what I've seen, this involves downloading a credentials json from the google console, which I've done but then running the script makes me go to a page to authenticate. This is not what I want to do, since this is an automated process that's going to run without user interaction. Is there a way that skip this step?

Edit: I've used http://localhost:8080 for the URI and http://localhost/ for the redirect, which seems to work for the given example but gives error 400 as soon as I change the scope to the link that I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Just use the defaults (or leave empty)
2. You must authenticate once with your browser. After you do that, your credentials will be written to a file (`token.json` in the referenced example). Store that file safely to your local drive and use it in subsequent calls. You will not need to authenticate through UI again:

   ```
   if os.path.exists('token.json'):
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
   ```

Comment: I ended up using http://localhost:8080 for the URI and http://localhost/ for the redirect URI and it seems to work (though I don't know why). As you said, once the token.json file is saved there's no more interaction needed in subsequent runs. However, if I change the scope from the example to the file I need to read, it stops working and gives me Error 400: invalid_scope

Comment: The score is not the url of the file, it is just a unique identifier. REF https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes&ved=2ahUKEwjzoI_Eg7XyAhX5_7sIHeSaAkQQFnoECAgQAg&usg=AOvVaw0svrJI2wG6y6hmW8xeQ4no

Comment: @Joolz The token is only granted for the original scopes. You need to delete the token.json file and reauthenticate after changing the scopes.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo  I have left the scope as is from the quickstart and changed the sample spreadsheet id and range for the values in the document.  I can reach the document, but have lost the ability to skip manual authentication after the first try. Now I have to delete the token.json file everytime I run this or I get ValueError: Authorized user info was not in the expected format, missing fields refresh_token.

Comment: I also note that my token json has an expiry field

Comment: [Check this answer out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66857607/11551468). It sounds like you have an issue with the credentials file.